# Cocoapods permissions No such file or dirrectory

Tags: cocoapods, chown

I have a problem here. I've installed cocoapods on my Mac because I need it for my XCode project. I've runned this command

```
gem install cocoapods
```

which works fine, all things were installed. But I after that when I tried to use any `pod COMMAND` thing, I've got the error - `You cannot run CocoaPods as root.`

I've looked through stackoverflow, and the main advices were to use this commands

`sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cocoapods` or `sudo chown -R $USER ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`

but the problem is none of those commands were working for me and I've got this error:

```
chown: /Users/user/.cocoapods: No such file or directory
```

Could you tell me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys, I've figured out the problem. Just need to do what the error says. You shouldn't run `pod install` command with `sudo` or from the root user. It means - just open new terminal window and don't log to the root user and work with `pod`